# async python logging details of AbstractEventLoop.slow_callback_duration

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm getting the following warnings in my python 3.6 code using:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG'] = '1'
```

```
Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fa8653dca08>(<Future finis...events.py:295>) created at /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py:390> took 5.012 seconds
Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fa8653dcc48>(<Future finis...events.py:295>) created at /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py:390> took 9.941 seconds
Executing <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fa8653dca08>(<Future finis...events.py:295>) created at /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py:390> took 5.038 seconds
```

So this is useful because I know things are being slow - but I'm having trouble figuring out if there is a way to get a better stack trace so I can actually track down what is happening.

Is there a way to get more of a stack trace out of this - I assume its triggering the `AbstractEventLoop.slow_callback_duration` as described here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-dev.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mind dirty tricks, do you? There are some hints:

1. Replace `asyncio.base_events._format_handle` with your own handle, a function with one argument, let's call it `handle`.
2. Look at `handle._source_traceback`, it might give you information where your task in originated from.
3. Take a look at `handle._callback`. In your case it's `TaskWakeupMethWrapper`, but there can be other alternatives.
4. `TaskWakeupMethWrapper` exposes nothin to public, but who can stop a true hacker?

There is a code to unwrap it with `ctypes`:

```
PyObject_HEAD = [
    ('ob_refcnt', ctypes.c_size_t),
    ('ob_type', ctypes.c_void_p),
]

class TaskWakeupMethWrapper_Structure(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = PyObject_HEAD + [
        ('ww_task', ctypes.py_object),
    ]


class PyAsyncGenASend_Structure(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = PyObject_HEAD + [
        ('ags_gen', ctypes.py_object),
        ('ags_sendval', ctypes.py_object),
        ('ags_state', ctypes.c_int),
    ]


def unwrap_task_wakeup_method(wrapper: 'TaskWakeupMethWrapper'):
    wrapper_p = ctypes.cast(
        ctypes.c_void_p(id(wrapper)),
        ctypes.POINTER(TaskWakeupMethWrapper_Structure),
    )
    return wrapper_p.contents.ww_task
```

5. Print the state of unwrapped coroutine (e.g. with `inspect.getcoroutinestate()`). Note, that the state is *after* slow code, so be ready to see just `CORO_CLOSED`.

Answer (score 0):

```
async def monitor_tasks():
    while True:
        tasks = [t for t in asyncio.all_tasks() if t is not asyncio.current_task()]
        [t.print_stack(limit=5) for t in tasks]
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # Start main event loop.
loop.create_task(monitor_tasks()) # To monitor stack trace
```

This is how I prefer to do it. You can print the stack trace with python's logging module.

Taken from this [great tutorial](https://www.roguelynn.com/words/asyncio-debugging/)